# Select in Method Syntax C# - returns a collection of anonymous object

Tags: c#, linq, methods, group-by

I need to use Select operator to shape the data in a linq method syntax to return a collection of anonymous object with the Name and Age property.I know how to write a query syntax for achieving this but not able to do it with a method syntax

See the 2 pieces of code, 1st one works fine, 2nd getting error indicating 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
"Error  CS1061  'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'StudentName' and no accessible extension method 'StudentName' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
var studentsGroupByStandard = from s in ObjectsMisc.studentList
                                          group s by s.StandardID into sg
                                          orderby sg.Key
                                          select new { sg.Key, sg };
```

```
var testS = ObjectsMisc
  .studentList
  .GroupBy(sg => sg.StandardID)
  .OrderBy(sg => sg.Key).Select(sg => new {
     Name = sg.StudentName,
     Age = s.Age
   });
```

so the 2nd piece generate a design error

Comment: So then what is the question? Out of a `GroupBy`, you get groups, they contain a Key, and then a collection of students (in this case). You say `var testS =`, but have you thought through what you want from this query? What is the result you want?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `Select(sg => new { sg.Key, sg })`?

Comment: The second query is not even similar to the first one. Look at the extreme differences in the select statement

Comment: The error tells you, that a group of students does not have a `StudentName`. I think Sweeper's correction is right.

Comment: No one ever reads exception messages :(

Comment: @Sweeper, or you can just return `IGrouping`, which already has `.Key` property and can be iterated ;)

Comment: Correct, Sweeps and wertzui 1st one are good

Comment: Then why in first one your have `sg.Key` and second one you have `sg.StudentName`? The two aren't the same, if you put `sg.StudentName` in the first one, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent Method syntax for your first query would be

```
var testS = ObjectsMisc.studentList
    .GroupBy(s => s.StandardID)
    .OrderBy(sg => sg.Key)
    .Select(sg => new { sg.Key, sg})
```

However this does not select the `StudentName` and `Age` properties, but the whole student objects.

If your students have a `StudentName` and an `Age` property and you want to select these grouped by `StandardId`, it would be the following method syntax

```
var testS = ObjectsMisc.studentList
    .GroupBy(s => s.StandardID)
    .OrderBy(sg => sg.Key)
    .Select(sg => new { sg.Key, Students = sg.Select(s => new { s.StudentName, s.Age }) })
```

Comment: Thanks wertzui, 1st piece of code is good but tnot the 2nd one, I am getting a red swiggly lines under "sg.Select(s => new { s.StudentName, s.Age " with following 2 errors: 
Error CS1026 ) expected and  ************
Error CS0746 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: As the error indicates, a `)` was missing and a member name was not declared. I corrected the code.